# Store the number of views of an image

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a folder on my web server containing lots of PNG images. I would like to store in a database the number of views each image gets. I do not really know how to achieve this. I can only think of using a .htaccess file to rewrite urls in that folder to a php script that would serve those images and also store the visit on MySQL. But maybe there is a better way than serving all the images through a PHP script. I am looking for the simplest possible way to do this. And also, current urls should not be changed.

Comment: Apache keeps a log of all requests in `access.log`. You could write a script which parses this log file for all requests to the images.

Comment: If the images are somehow stored in a DB Table, you could add an extra column called "views"(example), on every click of an image you can get the ID and than update the record with the current value of "views" +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a single "good" way to do this. But I cat give you few ideas.

1. (*recommended*) Make a proxy PHP script which will take ID (could be file name) of the picture. It will increment the counter in the DB and then redirect to original image.

   This is very clear way to achieve expected behaviour. Disadvantage is it changes current filenames. So you have to use following schema

   `CURRENT_URL -> (mod_rewrite) -> PHP PROXY SCRIPT -> NEW_URL`
2. Redirect all image urls to PHP proxy script which will directly server image (set appropriate headers and output content of file).

   This is 100% transparent way to do this but obvious disadvantage is that every image is processed by PHP. So when you have heavy-loaded server this could be problem.
3. If you have access to logs of web server (`access.log` for Apache) you can process this file say once a day and update counters in DB. This is very good when approximation is good enough and your server is heavy-loaded because you can parse logs on different machine.

Answer (score 0):

Apache already keeps a log file of all requests (`/var/log/apache2/access.log`). This file contains the URL requested, time of request etc.

A possible approach could be:

- Create a script which parses the access log and updates the database
- Configure a cronjob which invokes the script periodically